# How to Open VB.NET Form in Design Mode

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a VB.NET solution created in Visual Studio 2017. It seems like I used to double click Form1.vb in the Solution Explorer to open the form in design mode so I could add buttons and such.

Now no matter what I do, I can't open the design form window. It seems like there are fewer elements in the Solution Explorer, but I'm not sure:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to open the Form Designer again? Thanks.

Comment: Did you declare another class inside the same code file as the form? Did you also change the name of the form class in the code file?  It looks like you have done both, based on that screen shot. It's possible to do the former but the other class must come after the form in the code file, rather than before. It's better to keep each class to its own file though. As for the latter, it's also possible but you must change the name in both the user and designer code files. It's better to change the name in the Solution Explorer though, in which case you're prompted to change the class name.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I didn't change any class names, filenames, or entries in the Solution Explorer. It's a rather new project and I haven't had the need. The solution builds just fine, so it is finding the form design when it builds.   The folder contains a Form1.Designer.vb and a Form1.resx. I can double-click the Form1.Designer.vb file and it opens in VS 2017 and specifies the attributes and locations for all the items in the form. But I just can't figure out how to open the GUI view of the form.

Comment: So what are `ClientClass` and `ServerForm` and where are they declared?

Comment: I just found a saved copy of the solution from about two weeks ago. If I open it and double-click on form1.vb, it goes right to the form editor as expected.

Comment: ClientClass is an informational class used by the main form code and is not related to any forms. ServerForm is the main form of the program, which is listed as Form1 in the Solution Explorer. They are both declared in form1.vb.

Comment: So you have done exactly what I said then. You have got multiple classes declared in the same code file and you have changed the name of the form from `Form1` to `ServerForm`. Where EXACTLY is `ClientClass` declared?  Is it **BEFORE** `ServerForm`, **INSIDE** `ServerForm` or **AFTER** `ServerForm`?

Comment: ClientClass is defined first in Form1.vb, right after the imports statements. Next, ServerForm is defined in the same source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is exactly as I described in the first comment. Only the first type in a code file can be designed. If `ServerForm` is declared after `ClientClass` then `ServerForm` is not the first type in the code file, thus it cannot be designed. You could move `ClientClass` after `ServerForm` and that would address the issue but I would suggest doing what you should have done in the first place and declaring `ClientClass` in its own code file.

To that end, select the entire `ClientClass` definition and cut it to the Clipboard. Right-click your project in the Solution Explore and select Add > New Class and name it `ClientClass`, then select all the code in the new file and paste what you previously cut.  You should then be able to build your project and now open your form in the designer.

I have two further suggestions.  As I said, you appear to have renamed your form in the code.  Don't do that.  You now have the class name and file name out of sync.  If you want to rename a type then you should also rename the file it is declared in.  As you should almost always have just one type per file, they should be named the same.  If you right-click the item in the Solution Explorer and select Rename, you can rename the file and you will then be prompted to similarly rename the type, which you should accept.

Finally, you should pretty much NEVER use "Class" as a suffix on the name of a class.  You'll note that the `String` type is not named `StringClass`.  You really ought to rename your `ClientClass` type `Client`. You might want to elaborate on what type of client, but the "Class" suffix is not a good idea.

Comment: Great advice. I followed all of it and now everything is working as expected. Thanks for sticking with me and giving me a good solution.